# SQL Query to consolidate multiple records on one row based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to produce a SQL Query which looks at multiple rows and populates certain information in certain columns.  I am using SQL Server.

I have 2 tables a transaction table and a transaction data table.  Sample data below.

[image]

[image]

What I am after is a query which returns this:

[image]

The Bank Column and Amount Column should get their information from the record that has the bank as the Category (ie: first line in the TransData table for example) and the Category needs to be derived from the Category column if there is only one other record apart form the bank record, otherwise populates with 'Multiple'

Initially I thought this was relatively straight forward, but I was wrong, and now I am stuck.

The code I have got so far is:

```
SELECT
T.dtm_TransDate,
T.txt_Type,
T.txt_Description,
CASE
    WHEN TD.txt_Category = 'Current' THEN TD.txt_Category 
END AS 'Bank',
TD.dbl_Amount

FROM dbo.tbl_Trans AS T

JOIN dbo.tbl_TransData AS TD ON TD.int_TransID = T.int_Trans_ID

WHERE
(T.txt_Type = 'REC' OR T.txt_Type = 'PAY')
AND T.dtm_TransDate > '2019-02-01'
```

This produces every record, but I need to consolidate several records into one.

I did not know if I need to use a pivot for this, but unsure on how that works.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.  Any further information needed or clarified, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a self join.

Comment: Not sure on how to do that, I will research, thanks

Comment: Rather that imagse (which we can't use), please post your sample data as foramtted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements. Thanks.

Comment: Also, looking at your image, why is the value of `Amount` 1,000 in your expected results? I expected the value to be the sum of the amount, which is `1000 + (-800) + (-200) = 0` can you explain?

Comment: It is essentially  a double entry accounting system, where bank increases by 1000 and this is represented by selling prod A for 800 and prod B for 200.  Add them all together and they balance themselves out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work well for you.  Here, I have an inner query pre-grouping per transaction ID.  I am getting the sum of transactions only if associated with "BANK", but also getting the description and count.  At the same time, doing for those NOT as bank and getting the max description... if only one, great, you have it.  If more than one, you have the COUNTER for that too.

Then the outer query applies a test based on the COUNTER column to either retrieve the bank or category (multiple) respectively.

```
select
        T.TransID,
        T.TransDate,
        T.Reference,
        T.Description,
        case when PQ.CountOfBank = 1
            then PQ.SingleBank
            else 'Multiple Bank' end Bank,
        case when PQ.CountOfPurpose = 1
            then PQ.SinglePurpose
            else 'Multiple' end Category,
        PQ.SumOfBank amount
    from
        (select
                TD.TransID
                sum( case when TD.Category = 'Bank'
                        then TD.Amount else 0 end ) SumOfBank,
                sum( case when TD.Category = 'Bank'
                        then 1 else 0 end ) CountOfBank,
                max( case when TD.Category = 'Bank'
                        then TD.Category else ' ' end ) as SingleBank,
                sum( case when TD.Category = 'Bank'
                        then 0 else 1 end ) CountOfPurpose,
                max( case when TD.Category = 'Bank'
                        then ' ' else TD.Category end ) as SinglePurpose
            from
                TransData TD
            group by
                TD.TransID ) PQ
            JOIN Trans T
                on PQ.TransID = T.TransID
```

If you need a date filter applied, add that to the INNER PreQuery (PQ) WHERE clause portion.

Comment: That is fantastic.  It worked perfectly.  Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a `group by`?

```
SELECT T.dtm_TransDate, T.txt_Type, T.txt_Description,
       'BANK' as bank,  -- unclear what the logic is here
       (CASE WHEN MIN(TD.txt_Category) = MAX(TD.txt_Category)
             THEN MIN(TD.txt_Category)
             ELSE 'Multiple'
        END) as category,
     SUM(TD.dbl_Amount) as Amount
FROM dbo.tbl_Trans T JOIN
     dbo.tbl_TransData TD
     ON TD.int_TransID = T.int_Trans_ID
WHERE T.txt_Type IN ('REC', 'PAY') AND
      T.dtm_TransDate > '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY  T.dtm_TransDate, T.txt_Type, T.txt_Description,
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't give him the "Multiple" category description he's looking for.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this.  I can tackle the Multiple part after.  Maybe I could use a With first to calculate the number of records

Comment: Sorry did not do exactly what I wanted, but DRapp answered perfectly.  Many thanks for spending the time in replying

Comment: @francovici . . . It should.  I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use something similar to the below?:

```
SELECT
    T.dtm_TransDate,
    T.txt_Type,
    T.txt_Description,
    CASE
        WHEN TD.txt_Category = 'Current' THEN TD.txt_Category 
    END AS 'Bank',
    MAX(TD.dbl_Amount)
FROM dbo.tbl_Trans AS T
JOIN dbo.tbl_TransData AS TD ON TD.int_TransID = T.int_Trans_ID
WHERE (T.txt_Type = 'REC' OR T.txt_Type = 'PAY')
AND T.dtm_TransDate > '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY T.dtm_TransDate, T.txt_Type, T.txt_Description, TD.txt_Category
```

What I did here was add a MAX() on the Amount attribute taken from the second table. In theory what this does is get the greatest value of the TransID attribute you are joining on.

Hope this helps :)